# Messages sent to Azure servicebus using the .net client api can't be received using the Rest api

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to send and receive messages to the Azure servicebus using either the .net client api or the REST api.

I have followed the [REST api tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh416754.aspx) which works fine and I can send and receive messages using this.

However when I send a message which contains a custom object from our application using the .NET client and then try and receive this object using the REST api I get a server 500 error with a status of ProtocolError.  This is the code to receive the message:

```
    // Receives and deletes the next message from the given resource (Queue, Topic, or Subscription)
    // using the resourceName, the SWT token, and an HTTP DELETE request.
    private static string ReceiveAndDeleteMessage(string resourceName)
    {
        string fullAddress = baseAddress + resourceName + "/messages/head" + "?timeout=60";
        Console.WriteLine("\nRetrieving message from {0}", fullAddress);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = token;

        //falls over on this line
        byte[] response = webClient.UploadData(fullAddress, "DELETE", new byte[0]);            

        string responseStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
        Console.WriteLine(responseStr);
        return responseStr;
    }
```

The code which sends the message looks like this:

```
Message<T> message = GetMessage();

var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message)
   {
       Label = message.Label,
       CorrelationId = message.RequestId.ToString(),
       MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
   };

 MessageSender sender = GetMessageSender();
 return sender.SendAsync(brokeredMessage );
```

and the Message object is:

```
[MessageContract(WrapperName = "Message", WrapperNamespace = MessageAttributes.BaseNamespace, IsWrapped = true)]
public sealed class Message<T> where T : class
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = MessageAttributes.BaseNamespace, Name = "RequestId")]
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(Namespace = MessageAttributes.BaseNamespace, Name = "Label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = MessageAttributes.BaseNamespace, Name = "Payload")]
    public T Payload { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = MessageAttributes.BaseNamespace, Name = "MonitoringResults")]
    public MessageTimestamp MessageTimestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Why might this be? What is different about the messages? Are they not just a stream of bytes which I should receive and then deserialize back into my custom object?

I can happily receive the objects using the .net client to receive.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it seemed to work, can you set the content-type to "text/plain"?

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("DELETE", receiveUri, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", sasToken);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "text/plain");
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekLal I'm not sure why but after establishing that there was a bug with with the XML deserialisation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152085/why-cant-i-deserialize-my-object-if-the-xml-it-contains-gets-slightly-larger) I wasn't then able to reproduce the problem, and am able to get everything working